# How to check the alphanumeric condition in the Junit

Tags: android, testing, junit, junit4, junit5

I trying to write Junit test case for the login page.So i want to test the alpha numeric test  case .How to test the alpha numeric case in Junit .I had refereed this link[Junit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTestingEspresso/article.html)

Comment: Your question must provide more detail to receive an answer. In particular, what do you mean with "i want to test the alpha numeric test case"? Please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to check alpha numeric patterns.

```
Pattern.matches( ".", "1" );  //true
Pattern.matches( "\\d*", "12345" ); //true
Pattern.matches( "\\d*a", "12a" ); //true
Pattern.matches( "\\d*", "12a" ); //false
```